# Two Sorted Arrays, sum of 2 elements equal a certain number

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, big-o

I was wondering if I could get some help. I want to find an algorithm that is THETA(n) or linear time for determining whether 2 numbers in a 2 sorted arrays add up to a certain number.

For instance, let's say we have 2 sorted arrays: X and Y

I want to determine if there's an element of X and an element of Y that add up to exactly a certain number, let's say 50.

I have been able to come up with these algorithms in Python so far, but I am pretty sure they are order of THETA(n^2) rather than THETA(n).

```
def arrayTestOne(X,Y):
    S =[1 for x in X for y in Y if x+y == 50]

def arrayTestTwo(X,Y):
    for x in X:
        for y in Y:
            if x + y == 50:
                print("1")
```

I'm thinking it's the double for loops that break the linear time, but how else would you iterate through 2 lists? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me encourage you to spend more time thinking about this. Say the arrays are [1,2,...,10] and [10,20,...,100]. Try your algorithm by hand and see if you can spot where you're wasting time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is start with the highest in one list and the lowest in the other, and check the sum.

If the sum is your target, you're done.

If it's too high, go to the next highest value in the first list.

If it's too low, go to the next lowest value in the second.

If you go through both lists without reaching the target, you return false.

Comment: Liked your idea. Where did you get it from? :-)

Comment: @Bharel Not 100% sure, I think something similar came up in a class I had a year or two ago, though we were dealing with summing from three arrays instead of two.

Comment: What do you do in three arrays? Is there any general solution to N-arrays? In 3 arrays mine+your solution might just work btw.

Comment: Wouldn't this still be quadratic since in the worst case we are considering each value in both lists?

Comment: We consider potentially every element in each list, but we have at most |X| + |Y| iterations, which is O(max(X, Y)), as required.

Comment: @natalien This is because at each iteration, we discard an element from one list, or finish. A quadratic runtime would only occur if we had to compare each element of one list to each element of the other, which we aren't doing.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a 2n for you which doesn't even need sorting:

```
def check_array(x, y, needed_sum):
    y = set(y)
    return next(((i, needed_sum-i) for i in x if (needed_sum-i) in y), None)
```

Comment: Unless you're finding membership in y in constant time, I think this goes over the desired big-o runtime

Comment: @StephenTG `set()` is a hash table, thus `O(1)`.

Comment: Did not know that. Good to know

Comment: @StephenTG Actually, my answer is almost the same efficiency as yours. Yours is 1-2n mine is n-2n.

Comment: @StephenTG Don't worry, it's not really O(1).

Comment: @StefanPochmann well, it is a hashtable so it's `O(1) - O(n)` but if it's closer to `O(n)` it's not doing it's job very well, and python's hashtable works I believe.

Comment: @Bharel Yeah, they're annoyingly resilient... I just tried causing linear time with what I think I know about them, but failed :-). Might have to dig into the C source to understand it enough. Quite a challenge...

Comment: @stefan easier in Python 2. Python 3 adds salting to the hash and randomizes the seed.

Comment: @Bharel But not for numbers, right? Only for str, bytes and datetime objects.

Comment: @stefan I'm not entirely sure. Wanna check?

Comment: @StefanPochmann So, what are the results? Are numbers salted?