# 2 sum algorithm correctness of implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

The traditional two sum problem (my below reference implementation) is, for a sorted array, find all pairs of numbers which sum value is equal to a given target value. Traditional implementation scans from two ends of array, increase low index pointer if current sum is smaller than target value, decrease high index pointer if current sum is larger than target value.

My question is, is there a proof to show the correctness of this algorithm, showing that it does not miss a pair?

BTW, if my code has issues, please feel free to point out.

```
def twoSum(numbers, skipIndex, targetValue):
    i = 0
    j = len(numbers) - 1
    result = []
    while i < j:
        if i in skipIndex:
            i+=1
        if j in skipIndex:
            j+=1
        if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == targetValue:
            result.append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))
            i += 1
            j -= 1
        elif numbers[i] + numbers[j] > targetValue:
            j -= 1
        else:
            i += 1

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10]
    print twoSum(numbers, [1], 11) # output, [(1, 10), (4, 7), (5, 6)]
    print twoSum(numbers, [], 11) # output, [(1, 10), (2, 9), (4, 7), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Sorted Arrays, sum of 2 elements equal a certain number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581834/two-sorted-arrays-sum-of-2-elements-equal-a-certain-number)

Comment: @Bharel, my question is different from that one, I am more asking prove the correctness of the implementation method (scan from both ends, compare and move one of the pointer), other than how to implement. If I read it wrong for the other question, please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, retracted my close vote. Although I still believe it's a question for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think it belongs at math.stackexchange, and I do think it belongs here.. Whether it's a valid question without showing us what the OP has done to construct a proof is another matter..

Comment: @Bharel, thanks and I do not need a very mathematical prove, I just need to know it does not miss any numbers. If you have any good ideas, it will be great.

Comment: @thebjorn, thanks and I do not need a very mathematical prove, I just need to know it does not miss any numbers. If you have any good ideas, it will be great.

Comment: It's been a long time since I went to school, so let me just wave my hands a little.. You'll need to first prove that the algorithm stopped in the right spot - it should be easy to prove that any values found after `(5,6)` would just be transpositions of values already found. Second, you'll need to prove that the algorithm didn't skip any value-pairs - such proofs usually take the form of "assume there exists a `j` such that `i` + `j` is a match.." and then show that it will be included by the algorithm. It might help to first prove that the algorithm finds the value-pairs in sorted order..

Comment: @thebjorn, thanks for the idea and vote up. I think the first item is easy to prove since I record the pairs when their sum equal to target value by `result.append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))`, how do you think 2nd part of your claim could be proved?

Comment: If we skip the `skipIndex` and assume we've proven that the algorithm finds value-pairs in sorted order, then (premise) let's assume there exists a value `(a,b)`, with `a<b` that is missing and should have been included between `(i0, j0)` and `(i1, j1)`. Since the array is sorted and without duplicates, we have that `i0 < a < i1` (and similarly for `b`). If (base case) `a == i0 + 1` then the algorithm would find `a,b` either in its first iteration after `i0,j0` or when testing `a` against values in `<a..i1>`. (recursive step) If the algorithm has tested `i0+n` without finding the (cont.)

Comment: ..missing tuple `a,b`, and `a == i0+(n+1)` (here `n` and `n+1` are indices into the original array), then the algorithm will find the value because it "only steps one index per iteration". If `i0+(n+1) == j0`, then `a,b` cannot exist since `a` must be less than `j0`. Lots of hand-waving (it's 3am here), but the outline is an inductive proof that either the algorithm will find `a,b` between `i0,j0` and `i1,j1`; or `a,b` cannot exist in that interval.  That disproves our premise (reductio ad absurdum).

Comment: @thebjorn, excellent reply and vote up. If you could write a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people. Quick question, is it possible when lower index pointer points to a, higher index pointer already bypass b (I mean higher index pointer index < index of b)?

Comment: I don't think it's strong enough for an answer.. It looks like the if statements involved with the skip index should be while statements (in case there are adjacent skips). It would be easier to prove correctness if you first created a list without the skips.

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn, are there any bugs in my code if I do not write skip index check together with while (i.e. as my current implementation posted)? I think my code could handle adjacent skips, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just simplify the problem to find the first such pair, not all pairs (extending it to all pairs that add up to `targetValue` is straightforward).

Whenever you increase the left pointer `i`, you are throwing out the corresponding element from further consideration because when added with *any* other element in the array, the sum is still too small. So it is unusable. A similar argument follows for decrementing the right pointer `j`, with the tweak that the sum is too big rather than too small.

Another way to look at it is if you consider that modifying the pointers is the same thing as modifing the (sorted) list, because effectively it is the same thing as deleting the smallest and largest elements.

Lastly if the pointers ever cross, this is the same thing as the list becoming too small (<2 elements) to continue searching, and you are done.

What I described above is for the case of searching for the first pair that meets `targetValue`. To find all such pairs, you would simply continue to search as long as the pointers don't cross (instead of returning at the moment `targetValue` is found from the current pairwise sum). You've already done this with your `while i < j` condition (although for me personally `i != j` is more legible).

I am not sure what the utility of `skipIndex` is in your implementation (debug code?) but `j += 1` feels suspiciously buggy to me.

For further reading, I wrote a blog post: https://funloop.org/post/2020-12-05-twosum-problem-explained.html. I am not good at math so it is a non-mathy explanation.